# R - Convert objects of class circular back to numeric

Tags: r, circular-dependency

I am using the package circular in R to fit a von Mises distribution to a set of data:

```r
Mises <- mle.vonmises(x = angle, mu = NULL, kappa = NULL, bias = FALSE, control.circular = list())
```

The results are from the class circular. Is there a way to extract both mu and kappa to have them as numerics? I need to do that many times (I guess using `group_by()`), so writing down manually the displayed values of mu and kappa is not an option.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `mle.vonmises` is a `list`.

```
> str(Mises)
List of 8
 $ call     : language mle.vonmises(x = x)
 $ mu       : 'circular' num -0.0264  # it is a numeric value
  ..- attr(*, "circularp")=List of 6
  .. ..$ type    : chr "angles"
  .. ..$ units   : chr "radians"
  .. ..$ template: chr "none"
  .. ..$ modulo  : chr "asis"
  .. ..$ zero    : num 0
  .. ..$ rotation: chr "counter"
 $ kappa    : num 5.21
 $ se.mu    : num 0.0654
 $ se.kappa : num 0.973
 $ est.mu   : num 1
 $ est.kappa: num 1
 $ bias     : logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "mle.vonmises"
```

We can use standard extractors to extract the `list` elements ie. `$` or `[[`.  Regarding conversion to `numeric`, the `mu` is already `numeric` class.

```
> class(Mises$mu)
[1] "circular" "numeric"
```

It also include some `attr`ibutes with an additional class `circular` built on top of `numeric` which can be removed by either wrapping with `as.numeric` or `as.vector` or set the attributes to `NULL`

```
as.numeric(Mises$mu)
#[1] -0.02639894
Mises$kappa
[1] 5.214254
```

#### data

```
library(circular)
x <- rvonmises(n=50, mu=circular(0), kappa=5)
Mises <- mle.vonmises(x)
```